# Dojo custom component's property gives default always

Tags: dojo

I have written a custom component to create a html button.
custom component is defined as follows

```
dojo.provide("ovn.form.OvnButton") ;

require([ "dojo/_base/declare",
       "dojo/dom-construct",
       "dojo/parser",
       "dojo/ready",
       "dijit/_WidgetBase"],
       function (declare, domConstruct, parser, ready, _WidgetBase){

       return declare ("ovn.form.OvnButton",[_WidgetBase],{

            label: "unknown",            
            constructor : function(args){
                this.id = args.id;
                args.props.forEach(function(prop) {
                    if(prop.name == 'label'){
                        this.label = prop.value;
                        alert("found label " + this.label);
                    }                         
                });
                alert("from constructor " + this.label);
            },
            postMixInProperties : function(){
            },
            buildRendering : function(){

                alert("from renderer label is " + this.label);
                this.domNode = domConstruct.create("button", { innerHTML: this.label }); //domConstruct.toDom('<button>' + this.label + '</button>');
            },
            _getLabelAttr: function(){
                return this.label;
            },
            _setLabelAttr : function(label){
                alert("from set input is " + label)
                this.label = label;
            },             
            postCreate : function(){
                alert("Post create label is " + this.label);
            },
            startUP : function(){
            }
        });

});
```

This is how I am instantiating the component

```
var button = new ovn.form.OvnButton({
                          id:'run',
                          props:[{"name":"label","value":"Run"},{"name":"class","value":"btn"}]
                      });
```

In the constructor of the custom component, I am iterating through the array passed and assigning to the instance variable called 'label'. To my surprise when we print the instance variable in buildRendering function, it is still printing the default instead of the assigned value.

can somebody give some light on why this is so.

FYI:
I am getting the following sequence of messages on the console
1.found label Run
2. from constructor unknown
3. from renderer label is unknown
4. from set input is unknown
5. Post create label is unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because inside the little `forEach` function, `this` actually points to something completely different than your OvnButton object.

Javascript's `this` keyword is quite strange in this regard (it doesn't have anything to do with Dojo, actually). You can read more about how it works here: http://howtonode.org/what-is-this . It's a quite fundamental concept of Javascript, different from other languages, so it's well worth your time to get familiar with.

But there are various different ways you can quickly solve it, so here are a few!

### Use a regular for loop instead of forEach and callback

The easiest is probably to use a regular for loop instead of forEach with a callback.

```
....
// args.props.forEach(function(prop) {
for(var i = 0, l = args.props.length; i < l; i++) {
    var prop = args.props[i];    
    if(prop.name == 'label'){
        this.label = prop.value;
        alert("found label " + this.label);
    }                         
}//); <-- no longer need the closing parenthesis
```

The takeaway here is that Javascript's `this` magic only happens for function calls, so in this case, when we just use a for loop, `this` continues to point to the right thing.

### ... or use forEach's second thisArg argument

But perhaps you really want to use `forEach`. It actually has a second argument, often called `thisArg`. It tells `forEach` to make sure `this` points to something of your choice inside the callback function. So you would do something like this:

```
....
args.props.forEach(function(prop) {
            if(prop.name == 'label'){
                this.label = prop.value;
                alert("found label " + this.label);
            }                         
        }, this); // <--- notice we give forEach two arguments now,
                  //      the callback function _and_ a "thisArg" value
```

I'm not completely sure the above works in all browsers though, so here's another way to solve your issue:

### ... or use a temporary "self" variable

We will make a temporary variable equal to `this`. People often call such a variable `self`, but you can name it anything you want. This is important: it's only the `this` keyword that Javascript will treat differently inside the callback function:

```
....
var self = this; //<--- we basically give `this` an alternative
                 //     name to use inside the callback.
args.props.forEach(function(prop) {
            if(prop.name == 'label'){
                self.label = prop.value; //<--- replaced `this` with `self`
                alert("found label " + self.label); //<--- here as well
            }                         
        });
```

### ... or use hitch() from dojo/_base/lang

Some people don't like the `self` solution, perhaps because they like to consistently use `this` to refer to the owning object. Many frameworks therefore have a "bind" function, that makes sure a function is *always* called in a particular scope. In dojo's case, the function is called `hitch`. Here's how you can use it:

```
require([....., "dojo/_base/lang"], function(....., DojoLang) {
    ....
    args.props.forEach(DojoLang.hitch(this, function(prop) {
            if(prop.name == 'label'){
                this.label = prop.value;
                alert("found label " + this.label);
            }                         
        }));
```

### ... or use Javascript's own bind()

Dojo and pretty much every other framework out there has a hitch() function. Because it's such a commonly used concept in Javascript, the new Javascript standard actually introduces it's own variant, [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). You can use it like this:

```
....
args.props.forEach(function(prop) {
    if(prop.name == 'label'){
        this.label = prop.value;
        alert("found label " + this.label);
    }                         
}.bind(this));
```

---

That was a very long answer for a pretty small thing, I hope it makes some sense!